# How to handle multiple requests with the fastcgi program

Tags: c++, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I read the docs at `www.fastcgi.com` but I can't understand it.  How do I handle multiple requests in fastcgi?  Assuming I have nginx with config:

```
location ~ \.fcgi$ {
fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9999;
...
}
```

I have some fastCGI program (took from http://retechorg.ru/index.php?q=node/239).

So when I am in this while loop:

> while(FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)

When it takes a long time to clculate (say 1 minute calculation), or a sleep() it will block other requests.

How do I properly handle multiple requests in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process multiple requests at once, you need multiple threads, each executing the same main loop.

Comment: But do I need to use the same port (fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9999;) or need to have several ports (one port for one thread)?

Comment: I think you can use the same port, but you should try with a test program.